# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: bootstrap/base.html

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-bootstrap

I'm inheriting *bootstrap/base.html* in a Flask application after installing the Bootstrap Flask extension but having the below error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: bootstrap/base.html
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to import Bootstrap in this way below:

```
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
...
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
```

flask.ext.bootstrap is deprecated

Answer (score 2):

The answer is correct.

You can test settings in the execution file, for example: **flaskr/flaskr.py**

```
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
....
app = Flask(__name__)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

The problem should have been solved.

Answer (score 1):

Need to import Bootstrap from flask.ext.bootstrap and bootstrap the flask app as below:

```
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap
...
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
```

Comment: By the time you posted the question, the import should be done as shown in the accepted answer, instead.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a full flask project, u need to do these:

```
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
```

inside your `__init__.py` file