# Jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: bootstrap/base.html' error

Tags: python, flask

What could be causing the 'jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: bootstrap/base.html' error and how can it be resolved?

I understand that there is a Stack Overflow solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44318142/jinja2-exceptions-templatenotfound-bootstrap-base-html), but it has not helped.

Here is my server.py code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
import requests
import datetime


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '8BYkEfBA6O6donzWlSihBXox7C0sKR6b'
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///top_10_movies.db"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
Bootstrap(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

My index.html Code:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block styles %}
  {{ super() }}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans:300,400,700">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">
{% endblock %}
```

The base.html file location.
[The Image file Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ewbv.png)

I've tried removing the base.html file from the 'bootsrap' directory but it is still not working.